# Had a SQL table with date/hour, events and Latitude/Longitude. How to check if an event happened near other

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with this fields:
datetime, event_name, latitude, longitude

I want to create a boolean flag to know if an event happened near other in space and time, for example, if an event occurred within 2kms and 15 minutes

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Sorry im new here, which will be an appropriate tag? Postgresql (thats what im using)

Comment: Check out this info about the Haversine formula to calculate straight-line distance between two lat-long points. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula